# Is the service bus topic lose messages when I send a message without Forward To?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am new to the Message Queuing, so please correct me if I am mistaken.

I have a topic without subscriptions, let's call it "Sender". I have sent a message from my topic "Sender". What is going to happen to this message? I have tried this and I am losing the message.

**Notice:** that I am aware of all the filtering stuff before sending messages that can be used to overcome this scenario. However, I still want to know if there is any place I can find this sent message.

Answer (score 1):

Check Service bus topic properties for - "Message time to live" property once its expired the message gets moved to Dead letter queue.

You can use the Service Bus Explorer to check messages sent to topic and dead letter queue (once the message TTL expire).

You can download it from here: https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases

Here is a tutorial on how to use it: http://colinvermander.com/tag/service-bus-explorer/

And here is a link for more information about the software and features: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/paolos/2015/03/02/service-bus-explorer-2-6-now-available/